# Nest.js - is there another way to get request/body but by ParamDecorator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Somehow, ParamDecorator looks totally not cool. Is there another way to get the body or request? E.g. by function decorator or something global?

```
@Post('token')
public async createToken(@Body() body: UserLogin): Promise<any> {
  return await this.authService.signIn(body);
}
```

This is not working unfortunately.

```
@Post('token')
@Body('body')
public async createToken(body: UserLogin): Promise<any> {
  return await this.authService.signIn(body);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access body using request object

```
async getPostById(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
   const body = req.body;
   ...
}
```

But in this way you may ask you're using decorator to access request object !

Answer (score 2):

No there's no way to pull out this information without using Decorators on the function parameters themselves. What makes you feel like they are "not cool"? It doesn't seem like you gain much by moving them from the function params to the function.